# Querying MySQL tables for a item a user hasnt 'scored' yet

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
                      Tables
 __________________       ________________________________
|______name________|     |____________scores______________|
|___id___|__name___|     |_id_|_user-id_|_name-id_|_score_|
| 1      | bob     |     | 1  | 3       | 1       | 5     |
| 2      | susan   |     | 2  | 1       | 3       | 4     |
| 3      | geoff   |     | 3  | 3       | 2       | 3     |
| 4      | larry   |     | 4  | 2       | 4       | 5     |
| 5      | peter   |     | 5  | 1       | 1       | 0     |
--------------------     ----------------------------------
```

Im looking to write a query that returns a RANDOM name from the 'name' table, that the user hasnt scored so far.

So given user '1' for example, it could return 'susan, larry or peter' as user '1' hasnt given them a score yet.

```
SELECT * 
FROM names
LEFT JOIN 
votes
ON  names.id = votes.name_id
WHERE votes.user_id = 1
AND (votes.score IS NULL);
```

So far I have this, but it doesnt seem to be working as I would like 
(atm it doesnt return a random, but all, but this is wrong)
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are filtering on some field of outer joined table type of join is automatically changed to inner. In your case it's condition

```
votes.user_id = 1
```

So you need to move that condition from WHERE to ON

```
SELECT * 
FROM names
LEFT JOIN 
votes
ON  names.id = votes.name_id and votes.user_id = 1
WHERE (votes.score IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply :

```
SELECT name FROM name join scores on name.id=scores.user_id WHERE scores.score=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving the condition from `WHERE` to `JOIN ON` clause since you are performing an `OUTER JOIN` else the effect would be same as `INNER JOIN`

```
LEFT JOIN votes
ON  names.id = votes.name_id
AND votes.user_id = 1
WHERE votes.score IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this as a sub-query

```
SELECT * 
FROM names 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT name_id FROM votes WHERE user_id=1) 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```